# THREE JS cast shadow on gltf doesn't work

Tags: three.js

im still new, why the model does not cast any shadows? i have ambient lights and directional light enabled

```
// import model
const loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
loader.load( 'object/GalaxyS10.gltf', function ( gltf ) {
    scene.add( gltf.scene );
        
    }, undefined, function ( error ) {
        console.error( error );
    } 
);
loader.castShadow = true;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, your post misses a lot of details. In general, you have to do the following in order to achieve proper shadows:

- `GLTFLoader.castShadow` does not exist. Setting it has no effect.
- You have to add `renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;` to your code in order to globally enable shadows.
- You have to enable shadows on your shadow casting light. Since you are using a directional light, typical code looks like below. Notice that the configuration of the shadow frustum depends on the scale of your scene. You can visually debug the frustum via `CameraHelper`.

```js
const light = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff );
light.position.set( 0, 10, - 10 );
light.castShadow = true;
light.shadow.camera.top = 2;
light.shadow.camera.bottom = - 2;
light.shadow.camera.left = - 2;
light.shadow.camera.right = 2;
light.shadow.camera.near = 0.1;
light.shadow.camera.far = 10;
scene.add( light );

// scene.add( new THREE.CameraHelper( light.shadow.camera ) );
```

- You need some sort of ground or other objects that *receive* shadows. You have to set `receiveShadow` to `true` for those 3D objects.
- You have to define which objects should *cast* shadows by setting the respective property to `true`. You are not doing this in your code snippet. It should look like so:

```js
gltf.scene.traverse( function ( object ) {

    if ( object.isMesh ) object.castShadow = true;

} );
```